# Cannot connect to hive metastore on DBeaver

Tags: docker, hive, dbeaver, hive-metastore

So i've been working a project running Hive on a docker container that i got from this github link [https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive](https://stackoverflow.com). My objective is to get some metadata off hive tables inside of hive metastore but the problem is i cannot connect to the hive metastore on dbeaver using the following credentials of my hive-site.xml. Here's a picture of how does my hive containers looks like and the credentials of my metastore jdbc connecting url [image: Hive containers]

```
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name><value>jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore-postgresql/metastore</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name><value>org.postgresql.Driver</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name><value>********</value></property>
<property><name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name><value>hive</value></property>
```

Here's is a picture of the error i get [image: Dbeaver error]

i can connect to the hive metastore with no problems in the terminal using the psql command line `psql -U hive -d metastore -p 5432` but for this part of the personal project i have to do, testing the queries inside of the metastore terminal is beyond annoying. I can connect to the hive server using jdbc url jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 dbeaver but not to the metastore. Any tips on how to fix or approach this

I'm trying to connect to the hive metastore using dbeaver with right credential that i found on my hive-site.xml file but i'm getting an unexpected error.